# Converting TIFF file to bufferedImage

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a Tiff file to Buffered Image.
I used ImageIO to do that but i figured out that it doesn't support this type of files.

```
ImageIO.read(file);
```

Should i use other than ImageIO or there's a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put jai_imageio.jar in your classpath. check whether you have appropriate readers by using `ImageIO.getReadersByFormatName("tiff")`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Problem is i cant reach the plugins to download them , i ve searched in many links .

Comment: try [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaiimageio11jar.htm) to download the jar